# Help identify this camouflage military style jacket?

Tags: identification

[image][image]I have a camo military jacket I can't seem to find anywhere what it is. It has a paratrooper flap at the back. It has no labels.

Comment: Showing a bit more of the actual camo pattern in a second picture could be helpful, plus perhaps a bit more context. Can you tell us where you got it from, possibly limiting country of origin? -- I've gone through the various German *Flecktarn* patterns, and this doesn't seem to match any of them. Differences in details, and too light overall.

Comment: Is there any evidence that this is actually a military jacket? Or is this just a fashion item inspired by military uniforms?

Comment: Looks a bit like [DPM](http://camopedia.org/index.php?title=DPM), but not quite... and DPM was used all over the world. {shrug} Definitely not German, though, neither pre- nor post 1945.

Comment: Can we get a close-up of the buttons, inside of collar, breast pockets, both sleeves, and some seams and the zipper? And a description as to whether the colours are accurately captured? Are there indications that there *was* a label? In which country is this piece now, or is there anything to believe it came from somewhere else?

Comment: I don't think this is a US pattern. I've seen a lot of US camo and jackets, too. This is missing a way to attach a liner, too, which is something I've only seen in non-US jackets.

Comment: Hmmm... similar to British DPM but not "brushstrokey" enough, as you can see in LangLangC's answer. I could be wrong; there were several variants of British DPM over the years used by Britain, plus also New Zealand (and possibly other commonwealth countries) and Holland.  See https://camopedia.org/index.php?title=Main_Page for details.

Answer (score 1):

The picture still lacks details and different angles.

Pending clarification edits, a very rough idea would be:

This is some kind of a [DPM](http://camopedia.org/index.php?title=DPM) style garment. Even with much better pictures, it will be difficult to retroactively assign an *exact* diagnosis or identification.

[Disruptive pattern material](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disruptive_Pattern_Material) is a British camouflage style in origin but used elsewhere as well. It is also not exclusive to the British Army, but a popular choice in civilian military style clothing. The latter can vary in quite some details from 'the original'. Which [itself has quite the variation over time.](http://www.forces80.com/uniform.htm)

In this case it looks most likely *like* a 1968 pattern, (pre-85):

- '68 pattern Combat Suit (DPM) Smock, Man's Combat (1968 Pattern)

Parachutist version had a slightly different front, and especially cuffs, sniper version more external applications, but all some kind of crotch flap.

> [image]
> <sup>–– ["Early Pattern DPM Para Smock"](http://hmvf.co.uk/topic/18499-early-pattern-dpm-para-smock/)</sup>
>
> [image]
> <sup>–– [ebay auction: Smock DPM British Army "68 pattern" Camouflage Combat Jacket Camo New Condition](https://www.ebay.ph/itm/Smock-DPM-British-Army-68-pattern-Camouflage-Combat-Jacket-Camo-New-Condition-/191895730920)</sup>
>
> [image]
> <sup>–– The inside of the '68 Jacket is fully lined in Olive. It has a inside pocket on the left chest large enough to take an SLR Magazine and a pocket across the back below the waist. Also note the crotch flap. COMBAT UNIFORMS OF THE 1980's (A Beginners Guide)
> Part 1 DPM Uniforms</sup>

The pocket form indicates British style as well. Flat lower front pockets and visible buttons that are 'traditional' (sewed) and not 'Canadian' style (slotted) indicate an early design.

Colours as well as fabrics varied over time and for intended use. And weren't identical ever, as they also varied depending on manufacturer. Those colours pictured may also have faded or get a tint from washing. The amount of colours used indicate a temperate zone target deployment area.

Weird in the OP picture is the para-flap having *three* buttons, the whole thing *not* having the label.

But as to the changing over time design without updating the offical designation:

> [image]
> <sup>–– On the Left is an Early Pattern and on the Right is a Late Pattern '68 Jacket and Trousers.</sup>